# How to add onBlur property from Formik library to PhoneInput from react-international-phone library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I want to use Formik props like onBlur, errors, touched with PhoneInput component from react-international-phone library.
For now I tried to implement onBlur but I failed. Can You please suggest what is wrong and how should I connect those 2 libraries properly ?

This is my main component :

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: currentUser?.firstName || '',
      lastName: currentUser?.lastName || '',
      patient: {
        phoneNumber: currentUser?.patient?.phoneNumber || '',
        nationalId: currentUser?.patient?.nationalId || '',
        birthDate: currentUser?.patient?.birthDate || '',
        address: {
          street: currentUser?.patient?.address.street || '',
          building: currentUser?.patient?.address.building || '',
          apartment: currentUser?.patient?.address.apartment || '',
          city: currentUser?.patient?.address.city || '',
        },
      },
    },
    validationSchema: ValidationProfileSchema,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      await user.patchUser(values);
      toast({ title: t('toast.uptadeData') });
    },
  });



<PhoneNumberInputComponent
          id="patient.phoneNumber"
          values={formik.values.patient.phoneNumber}
          errors={t(formik.errors.patient?.phoneNumber ?? '')}
          touched={formik.touched.patient?.phoneNumber}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          onChange={(number: string) => formik.setFieldValue('patient.phoneNumber', number)}
          placeholder={t('profile.phone')}
          label={t('profile.phone')}
        />
```

And here is component implementation

```
interface PhoneNumberInputProps extends PhoneInputProps {
  id: string;
  onBlur: (id: string) => void;
}
export const PhoneNumberInputComponent: FC<PhoneNumberInputProps & FormikValues> = ({
  onChange,
  values,
  placeholder,
  label,
  id,
  onBlur: customOnBlur,
  errors,
  touched,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  console.log('blur', customOnBlur);
  console.log('touched', touched);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('works');
    if (touched && customOnBlur) {
      customOnBlur(id);
    }
  }, [touched, customOnBlur]);
  return (
    <FormControl isInvalid={touched && errors}>
      <FormLabel>{label}</FormLabel>
      <PhoneInput
        {...rest}
        onBlur={customOnBlur}
        defaultCountry="pl"
        value={values}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

With this code I get an error that onBlur don't exist on type "IntrinsicAttributes & PhoneInputProps"

thanks